# Replace a group of characters ( text = text.replace('aa','2')) in android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application for Android. Now I want to replace a character with another one.

for one character I'm working with

```
    String text = edit.getText().toString();
    text = text.replace('a', '2');
```

and its working fine.
when i want to replace two characters

```
    text = text.replace('aa', '3');
```

It gives me invalid character constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your single quotes (which denote single characters) with double quotes (which denote strings of one or more characters):

```
text = text.replace("aa", "3");
```